# JavaScript getting txt file info not working, no errors

Tags: javascript, html

I'm using the code bellow to store everything in a text file into a JavaScript var which than will go into a html id and it will be displayed.

```js
var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
client.open('GET', '/old.txt');
client.onreadystatechange = function() {
  alert(client.responseText);
}
client.send();
window.onload = function(){
    var lengthOfName = client.length

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = lengthOfName;
};
```

but the `output` id will show nothing in html.

Can anyone help me with this please?

Comment: `window.onload` doesn't wait for the AJAX to complete.

Comment: @Barmar how to run the code after the AJAX has been complete?

Comment: I posted it in an answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`window.onload` doesn't wait for the AJAX to complete. You should put the AJAX code inside the `onload` function, and assign to `innerHTML` inside the `onreadystatechange` function.

Also, `client.length` makes no sense. `client` is the XHR object, not an array or string, it doesn't have a length. I think you want `client.responseText.length`.

```js
window.onload = function() {
  var client = new XMLHttpRequest();
  client.open('GET', '/old.txt');
  client.onreadystatechange = function() {
    alert(client.responseText);
    var lengthOfName = client.responseText.length

    document.getElementById('output').innerHTML = lengthOfName;
  }
  client.send();
};
```

Comment: when i ran this the page said local host says and than the things in the file, how could this be fixed?

Comment: I have no idea what that means. What was the exact error message?

Comment: What is `client.length` supposed to be? I think you mean `client.responseText.length`

Comment: there is no errors, there is just a pup up message on the page that says: localhost63342 says {text file stuff}

Comment: That's what `alert(client.responseText)` does.

Comment: i put ``client.responseText.length`` but still the same thing happens

Comment: Of course the same thing happens. Why do you have that alert if you don't want the popup?

Comment: i have just fix it